# Remap a key that is used by default in nvim

Tags: neovim

I want to use K to jump 10 lines up but K is already used to open man page of the command I have the cursor on.
I'm using

```
:nmap K 10k
```

but nvim use the default function of the key.

How can I remap a key that is used by default?

Comment: I assume you mean K to jump 10 lines _up_. Your remap works for me in regular vim.

Comment: What is the output of command `:verbose nmap K`?